# How do I create an installer for Visual Studio 2008 addin?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, add-in

I have done an addin (in C#) for visual studio, (almost) ready to deploy it. But I don't know how to do an installer for that.

I saw the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112941/create-program-installer-in-visual-studio-2005) but I don't know where to go from there...

[This](http://hurtsmybrains.wordpress.com/2008/02/22/writing-an-installer-class-for-a-visual-studionet-addin/) seemed to be useful, but I don't understand where to start, put which code snippet where...

Can someone guide me from the basics? Can't find the resources online I want :(

Comment: If my answer was what you are looking for please accept

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps, led me down the right path.

This is a real in depth from concept to implementation:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/LineCounterAddin.aspx

Found this also interesting:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsx/thread/cb5958f4-b503-456b-af24-ebfdde8ec6ad

http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/MZ2008011.aspx

Wix is a great tool to deploy:

http://wix.sourceforge.net/votive.html

Any questions let me know.